# Disable all warning during ndk-build

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to disable all warnings during the 'ndk-build' process for compiling CPP code to be used with JNI on Android.

I'm using `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-error` with not success.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

OK. Got it. Put this line in your Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -w
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work for me, I am still seeing the warnings in the console.

Comment: This works for clang. You can find more options here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages